# Javascript replace event "mousedown" with "spacebar"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this little game in HTML with javascript and to play the game I need to click on mouse but I want to replace with spacebar.

```
var evt = "touchstart";
   if (width >= 500) {
      width  = 320;
      height = 480;
      canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";
      evt = "mousedown";    
   }
```

How can I use spacebar as "mousedown"?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to check for both spacebar and moousedown and trigger the function if any of them happened. provide your full code to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the event type to `keydown`, and check for the spacebars `keycode` which is 32.

Here is an example of what that would look like:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    console.log('Spacebar pressed');
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked! But if I wanted to use spacebar and mousedown? Player could use whatever he wanted.

Comment: @DanielPereira, Do you mean that you would want to require the user to have both the spacebar pressed, and the mouse down at the same time?

Comment: Nop, the user can use the mouse (mousedown) to play or the keyboard (spacebar). 
Thanks for your help!